# Build error in project developed on older version of Xcode and reopened on Xcode 12.5?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I encountered these errors when running my project on the new version of Xcode 12.5:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CFError?>'

> 1. Arguments to generic parameter 'Pointee' ('SecTrustResultType' and 'CFError?') are expected to be equal

Previously I had worked on the old versions of Xcode (Version 11 and Swift 5).

```
private func trustIsValid(_ trust: SecTrust) -> Bool {
    var isValid = false

    var result = SecTrustResultType.invalid
    let status = SecTrustEvaluateWithError(trust, &result) // code string where it gives me this error

    if status == errSecSuccess {
        let unspecified = SecTrustResultType.unspecified
        let proceed = SecTrustResultType.proceed


        isValid = result == unspecified || result == proceed
    }

    return isValid
}
```

Comment: Please copy the error text *into the post.*

Comment: Do not post pictures of errors.

Comment: I don't believe this code ever compiled. The second parameter should be a pointer to an Optional error, not a result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this code ever compiled. The second parameter should be a pointer to an Optional error, not a result.

In any case, you can just pass nil as the second parameter.  To get a result, call https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1396077-sectrustgettrustresult.